# Issues logging in a new account on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, email, passwords, user-folders

I made a new child account for the first time in a Microsoft Family Group using an email address. Whenever I log in, it shows the blue screen with a loading icon that you normally would see upon logging in to a new account for the first time, and then it asks for the password to the *email*, not the actual account's password. It also seems to sometimes make a new folder in C:\Users named defaultuser100000, defaultuser100001, defaultuser10000.[name of this computer], or defaultuser100001.[name of this computer]. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are not too far along, delete the account, restart the computer, and try making the account again.

Comment: I would guess there's an error in the Default user directory, which contains the "seed" files any fresh logon to a computer is created with. Create another new user and login and see if that works properly or not. If it does work OK, the problem is likely with the Microsoft side of the account. If it has the same symptoms, the problem is with your computer software and you should proceed with standard Windows repair steps.

Comment: @John I actually made the account twice after witnessing this problem but did not restart in between. I would certainly rather not delete the account, but if all else fail I guess that's what I'll do.

Comment: After setting a PIN, this problem seems to be gone. Should I delete the defaultuser directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting a PIN, this problem was gone. I also deleted the defaultuser directories with no problem.